# Why do we call "Pretrained model"

Tags: machine-learning

What I understood is that a

> model is the result of a training algorithm.

Set of parameters learned by the training algorithm is model

Since a model is already a trained one,then why do we say "Pretrained models"

If there are any misconception,please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

To briefly explain, a pre-trained model is a model that was trained on a large benchmark dataset to solve a problem similar to the one that we want to solve. It is a model created by someone else to solve a similar problem.

> Why do we call the Pretrained model?

It is because instead of building a model from scratch to solve a similar problem, you use the model trained on other similar problems as a starting point. Hence the name `Pretrained model`.